# Why my SelectListItem can not be edited ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to get the point and solve problem with `SelectListItem`. As Admin I want to be able to assign `Client` to register `User`

```
public IActionResult Edit(string Id)
{
    var user = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var userRole = _db.UserRoles.ToList();
    var roles = _db.Roles.ToList();
    var client = _db.Clients.ToList();
    var role = userRole.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.Id);

    if (role != null)
    {
        user.Role = roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == role.RoleId).Id;
    }

    if(client != null)
    {
        
    }

    user.RoleList = _db.Roles.Select(u => new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem
    {
        Text = u.Name,
        Value = u.Id
    });

    user.ClientList = _db.Clients.Select(u => new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem
    {
        Text = u.Name,
        Value = u.Id.ToString()
    });
    

    return View(user);
}



[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ApplicationUser user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var objFromDb = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Id);

        if (objFromDb == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var userRole = _db.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == objFromDb.Id);

        if (userRole != null)
        {
            var previousRoleName = _db.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == userRole.RoleId).Select(e => e.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(objFromDb, previousRoleName);
        }

        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(objFromDb, _db.Roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Role).Name);
        objFromDb.Name = user.Name;
        objFromDb.Email = user.Email;
        objFromDb.PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
        objFromDb.StreetAddress = user.StreetAddress;
        objFromDb.City = user.City;
        objFromDb.PostalCode = user.PostalCode;
        objFromDb.RoleList = user.RoleList;
        objFromDb.ClientList = user.ClientList;
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    user.RoleList = _db.Roles.Select(u => new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem
    {
        Text = u.Name,
        Value = u.Id
    });

    user.ClientList = _db.Clients.Select(u => new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem
    {
        Text = u.Name,
        Value = u.Id.ToString()
    });

    return View(user);
}
```

Somehow everything works fine only I can not change `ClientList` and I try to debug application but I can not see anything wrong.
I would be very thankfull If someone could check code and tell me where I made mistake ? What is wrong with this code, why my `ClientList` cannot be `Edited`

Answer (score 0):

The error message tell me that `ModelState` is false and I notice error here

```
objFromDb.ClientList = user.ClientList;
```

And I change to

```
objFromDb.ClientId= user.ClientId;
```

And now it works ! :)